# How to make MSTest to run tests in parallel using the command prompt

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, mstest

I am usimg MSTest.exe tool to run my Integration tests using a command prompt (in a powershell script).

But I see that it is running very slow and I need to run it faster.
Looking at the powershell output it seems like MSTest actually runs them one by one.

Is there a way to run them all together or in parallel?

I'm running the Tests with this command:

```
MSTest.exe "/testcontainer:C:\myTestClass.dll" "/resultsfile:C:\TestResult.trx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use testsettings for that.

Add a .testsettings file in the same folder where your test dll exists.

Your .testsettings file should look like this (note the ""parallelTestCount"" attribute on the Execution element):

```
<TestSettings name="SecurityWebApi" id="5f0defa1-d6a5-40a6-94ae-1522a7aeeba8" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Execution parallelTestCount="5">
    <TestTypeSpecific>
      <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdc9d9-dd`enter code here`b5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b">
        <AssemblyResolution>
          <TestDirectory useLoadContext="true" />
        </AssemblyResolution>
      </UnitTestRunConfig>
      <WebTestRunConfiguration testTypeId="4e7599fa-5ecb-43e9-a887-cd63cf72d207">
        <Browser name="Internet Explorer 7.0">
          <Headers>
            <Header name="User-Agent" value="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)" />
            <Header name="Accept" value="*/*" />
            <Header name="Accept-Language" value="{{$IEAcceptLanguage}}" />
            <Header name="Accept-Encoding" value="GZIP" />
          </Headers>
        </Browser>
      </WebTestRunConfiguration>
    </TestTypeSpecific>
    <AgentRule name="LocalMachineDefaultRole">
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
  <Properties />
</TestSettings>
```

Then in your command you can use it like this:

```
MSTest.exe "/testcontainer:C:\myTestClass.dll" "/runsettings:yourfile.runsettings" "/resultsfile:C:\TestResult.trx"
```